# Symfony 3.1 translation with custom domain shows already translated messages

Tags: translation, symfony, symfony-3.1

### INTRODUCTION

I am using Symfony v3.1.1 and found strange behavior while translating form submit button label.

I am using `domain_name.locale.xliff` files.

### DESCRIPTION

Label is translated correctly, but there is one extra translation showing up in Translation Messages missing section!

[See screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2beD.png),
[See screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuMZb.png)

1. What is strange is that missing translation is just a translated word, but i am using `generally.approximately.precisely` notation and in template there is no single words.
2. Also the phantom translation happens to show itself in `messages` domain, but `messages` domain is not used in that template...

relevant part of my twig template:

```
{% set button_submit_label = "admin.button.chooseDate"|trans({}, "admin") %}
{{ form_row(form.submit, {'label': button_submit_label, 'attr': {'class': 'button-choose-date small success'}}) }}
```

Invalid translation item is showing in the debug toolbar.

[See screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2beD.png),
[See screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuMZb.png)

### CODE

my ClickType that I use in form

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class ClickType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('from_date', DateType::class,
                array(
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'label' => false,
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'
                )
            )
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class,
                array(
                    'label' => false
                )
            )
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Click',
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Complete twig template:

```
{% extends 'admin.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ "admin.title.clicks"|trans({}, "admin") }}{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="content">
        {% block page %}

            {% block admin_menu %}
                {% include 'admin/admin_top_menu.html.twig' with {'admin_active': '6'} %}
            {% endblock %}

            {% block admin_content %}
                <div class="box-choose-date row clearfix text-center">
                    {% set from_date = app.request.get('from_date') %}
                    {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'form-choose-date'}, 'method': 'GET'}) }}
                    <fieldset>
                        <p class="clicks-choose-date">{{ "admin.msg.clicksChooseDate"|trans({}, "admin") }}</p>
                        {% if (from_date != '') %}
                            <p class="clicks-you-chose">{{ "admin.msg.clicksSinceDate"|trans({'%from_date%': from_date|date("d.m.Y")}, "admin") }} {{ "admin.msg.foundClicks"|transchoice(click_count, {'%click_count%': click_count}, "admin") }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                        {{ form_row(form.from_date, {'name': from_date, 'attr': {'class': 'input-date'}}) }}
                        {% if (from_date != '') %}
                            {% if (msg != '') %}
                                <p class="clicks-record-not-found">{{ msg }}</p>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {% set button_submit_label = "admin.button.chooseDate"|trans({}, "admin") %}
                        {{ form_row(form.submit, {'label': button_submit_label, 'attr': {'class': 'button-choose-date small success'}}) }}
                    </fieldset>
                    {{ form_end(form) }}
                </div>
                {% include 'admin/click_list.html.twig' with {'from_date': from_date, 'click_count': click_count} %}
            {% endblock %}

            {% block admin_footer %}
                {% include 'admin/admin_footer.html.twig' %}
            {% endblock %}

        {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

### UPDATE

Tested in Symfony 3.1.2, the same phantom translated string is displayed in Symfony profiler.

### CONCLUSION

Is it a bug in Symfony or am I doing something wrong?

Please advise.

Thank You for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sebastiaan Stok answered this question [on Github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19332#issuecomment-231671082).

> A label is always run trough the translator in the template, even if it's already translated (in the FormType or template calling form_row with a custom label). [form_div_layout.html.twig line: 213](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L213).

One can prevent this by setting the translation_domain to false:

```
{% set button_submit_label = "admin.button.chooseDate"|trans({}, "admin") %}
{{ form_row(form.submit, {'label': button_submit_label, translation_domain: false, 'attr': {'class': 'button-choose-date small success'}}) }}
```